# How can I open a Word document from within Power Apps running in Teams?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-teams, powerapps

I have created a Power Apps application that runs within a MS Teams channel.
The app lists a number of MS Office documents located in a master SharePoint library.
When a document is clicked the app copies the document from the master SharePoint library across to the local Teams Channel Files library.

Anyone know how I can automate the open of the document that now lives in the MS Teams channel Files library?

-- Edit --

I'm using Power Automate to copy the file between the SharePoint libraries. Power Automate returns the destination file path. Unfortunately If I Launch() that url, the file is downloaded - Not opened.

Comment: **Thank You** for accepting answer, this will help others in the community with similar question. Could you please spare one min to let us know how we did by clicking on **[this feedback link](https://aka.ms/DevSupportFeedback)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use deeplink to  automate. You can generate a deeplink to your file and automate.  Here is a sample format for deeplink to files -
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/file/5E0154FC-F2B4-4DA5-8CDA-F096E72C0A80?tenantId=72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47&fileType=pptx&objectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmicrosoft.sharepoint.com%2Fteams%2FActionPlatform%2FShared%20Documents%2FFC7-%20Bot%20and%20Action%20Infra%2FKaizala%20Actions%20in%20Adaptive%20Cards%20-%20Deck.pptx&baseUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmicrosoft.sharepoint.com%2Fteams%2FActionPlatform&serviceName=teams&threadId=19:f8fbfc4d89e24ef5b3b8692538cebeb7@thread.skype&groupId=ae063b79-5315-4ddb-ba70-27328ba6c31e.
This is the serialization of this object:

```
{
tenantId: “72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47”,
filetype: = “pptx”,
objectUrl: “https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/ActionPlatform/Shared Documents/FC7- Bot and Action Infra/Kaizala Actions in Adaptive Cards - Deck.pptx”,
baseUrl: “https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/ActionPlatform”,
serviceName: “teams”,
threadId: = “19:f8fbfc4d89e24ef5b3b8692538cebeb7@thread.skype”,
groupId: “ae063b79-5315-4ddb-ba70-27328ba6c31e”
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw that url when I clicked on 'Copy Link' in the library. When building the link, how would I get the threadId and groupId? I'm not really sure what these are.

Comment: Thread id means channel id. Group id means team id.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to get those ids. If anyone is interested this article shows how https://www.avepoint.com/blog/microsoft-teams/microsoft-teams-power-apps-build/

Comment: You can get group id and channel id using [Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). Could you please check these docs get [channel id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), in the same way you get group id using this endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups. You can fetch id's from the response

Comment: I may look in the future. For the moment i'm just getting group id and channel id from Teams via Param("groupId"), Param("channelId"). I'm trying to find where all the Params are documented.

Comment: https://regarding365.com/creating-teams-aware-power-apps-2fec4f0fc4c4